# Smaller Code (Python) for windows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to compress this code to be even smaller while not losing any functionality.

```
import math
from tkinter import*
C=Tk()
f=DoubleVar()
s=DoubleVar()
o=IntVar()
b=Radiobutton
e=Entry
c='c'
e(C,textvariable=f,justify=c).grid()
e(C,textvariable=s,justify=c).grid(row=0,column=1)
b(C,text='Add',variable=o,value=1).grid(row=2)
b(C,text='Subtract',variable=o,value=2).grid(column=1,row=2)
b(C,text='Multiply',variable=o,value=3).grid(row=3)
b(C,text='Divide',variable=o,value=4).grid(column=1,row=3)
b(C,text='Square',variable=o,value=5).grid(row=4)
b(C,text='Square root',variable=o,value=6).grid(column=1,row=4)
Button(C,text='Results',command=C.destroy,width=16).grid(row=7)
C.mainloop()
S=s.get()
O=o.get()
F=f.get()
if O==1:
    R=F+S
if O==2:
    R=F-S
if O==3:
    R=F*S
if O==4:
    R=F/S
if O==5:
    R=math.pow(F,S)
if O==6:
    R=F*(1/S)
print(R)
```

The GUI looks like this and it prints in answer on the shell

[image: The GUI looks like this and it prints in answer on the shell]

I would like to know without losing any functionality, if the size in bytes can be even less. it is currently 807 bytes in size. Thank you

Comment: According to https://mothereff.in/byte-counter which is used over on codegolf, this program is 771 bytes.

Comment: I was using the 'properties' option on windows 10

Comment: Ah, I'm used to seeing that byte counter used on code golf. Have you seen both answers that have been provided, do either of them do what you want? If not, how can I change my answer?

Comment: Both work, but as i am relatively new, i am not 100% familiar. This is a school project that i can take these skills and put these in my Major Project. As a new person however certain commands are new like 'lambda' , 'exec' and 'enumerate'

Comment: If you look up Python tutorials, these are all well documented commands. If this is a school project, then try and minimise it yourself, perhaps sit with your teacher and go through it with them.

Comment: Is there any websites you recommend?

Comment: Yes, Google is a good place to start

Comment: Ok, thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

Python was created to create readable code but if you need unreadable code then:

`if` with one line of code doesn't need indention:

```
if O==1:R=F+S
if O==2:R=F-S
if O==3:R=F*S
if O==4:R=F/S
if O==5:R=math.pow(F,S)
if O==6:R=F*(1/S)
```

On Windows `new line` (`Enter`) mostly uses two bytes (`0x0A` and `0x0D`)
but you can use `;` (one byte) to put some code in one line:

```
import math;from tkinter import*;C=Tk();f=DoubleVar(); ...
```

It doesn't work with `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `def` and other commands which use indentions.
On Linux/MacOS `new line` uses only one byte (`0x0A` or `0x0D`) so it make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only functionality that you want to keep then if you ditch the `Radiobutton`s and go for `Button`s instead then you can cut it down to 368 bytes:

```
import math;from tkinter import*;c=Tk();e=Entry;x=DoubleVar();y=DoubleVar();e(c,textvariable=x).grid();e(c,textvariable=y).grid();[Button(c,text=i[0],command=lambda m=i[1]:exec("F=x.get();S=y.get();print("+m+")")).grid() for a, i in enumerate([('Add',"F+S"),('Subtract',"F-S"),('Multiply',"F*S"),('Divide',"F/S"),('Square',"math.pow(F,S)"),('Square root',"F*(1/S)")])]
```

This is by no means the smallest you can go. Trust me, [this rabbit hole runs deep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

If you want to keep the formatting you have you can cut it down to 450 bytes:

```
import math;from tkinter import*;c=Tk();e=Entry;x=DoubleVar();y=DoubleVar();e(c,textvariable=x).grid();e(c,textvariable=y).grid(row=0,column=1);[Button(c,text=i[0],command=lambda m=i[1]:exec("F=x.get();S=y.get();print("+m+")")).grid(column=i[2],row=i[3]) for a, i in enumerate([('Add',"F+S","0","2"),('Subtract',"F-S","1","2"),('Multiply',"F*S","0","3"),('Divide',"F/S","1","3"),('Square',"math.pow(F,S)","0","4"),('Square root',"F*(1/S)","1","4")])]
```

Again, this isn't the smallest you can do, just the smallest I could be bothered to cut it down to.

This also relies on you switching from `Radiobutton`s to `Button`s.

This also isn't really the point of Python which is supposed to be for writing easily readable code, which this is not.